# Magento 2 - Get order collection of current month and placed by new and older customer

Tags: collection, magento2.4.1, order-collection

I want to get the two order collections by new and older customers for the current month.

Please suggest the proper way, I just want the count of orders, Not need all the details of an order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: new and older customers - so all customers?

Comment: Yes, New means who placed order first time in this month and older means repeated customer who placed an order before this month.